# Is it possible to save the output of a previous command on file?

Tags: bash, terminal

Quite often, I'm in the following situation: I launch a command on bash (that  takes lot of time to be processes) and I get a long output,  which doesn't fit into the terminal and it can't be read even using the scrolling.
The only way I have to read it is to redirect the output to a file. In order to do so, I have to relaunch the command, something that I want to avoid as I would take too much time.

I simply want to print on file the output that has been generated in the prevous command.

It there any way to do that?

Al.

PS: for example, I give

```
diff folder1 folder2 #the folders contain many files
```

wait 60 seconds, and *after* I decide to print the output

Comment: which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: @lese I use GNOME Terminal (v 2.31.3) and MATE Terminal (don't remember the version). I would be happy to change but I can't (no root privileges).

Comment: do you need root proviledges to change the gnome terminal configuration? I don't think so : )

Comment: @lese Perhaps I should say I don't know how... :-$

Comment: @altroware Ok let me understand your problem. You executed a command, it gives you a very long output that you can't read even scrolling up your terminal screen. You want to save THAT GIVEN output to a file? Avoiding to execute the command again?

Comment: @tachomi Yes, indeed!

Comment: @altroware, you don't know how? I described it in my answer. Just right click on the terminal > profiles > profile preferences > scrolling (tab) > activate the checkbox for unlimited scolling backward.

Comment: @lese Thanks for this, I would vote up your answer, but I dont' have yet enough reputation. Actually, I was looking for a bash command to save it on file.

Comment: You are welcome. Then I think the answer provided by MelBurslan should be the one better fits you needs. Just read again what he wrote and follow correctly the hints ; )

Comment: @lese That seems great, It looks like I don't have the permission to do that! Doing `bash-4.1$ script`, I get:
`typescript: Permission denied
Terminated
`

Comment: I honestly don't know any other solution without superuser permissions. Are you sure you are not in the sudoers group? try `sudo script`

Comment: mmm or maybe, you are just in a folder where you can read but you cannot write. Try this: `cd ~` to change directory into your home. There you can write. Then again: `script` and so on : )

Comment: Yes! :) I think that this would just solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a suspicion that, such a thing, i.e., a long output, to happen, start your session by executing command

```
script
```

this will log all your screen output as well as what you type in to the terminal (caveat emptor, backspaces and other normally unprintable characters will make the file harder to read, if you are not careful).

when you are done executing your long winded command, just type `exit` and it will tell you it saved the session output in a file called `typescript`. Also you can change the name of this file by running your command as

```
script my_output_file_name
```

It is a good tool for debugging scripts etc.

Comment: Very interesting, but I get this: `bash-4.1$ script file`
`file: Permission denied 
Terminated bash-4.1$ `

Comment: OK, as notices by @lese this was due to a folder where I could read but I couldn't write. Thanks!

Comment: script ~/somefile; # or # script /some/path/you/can/write/to

Comment: This is a useful solution; yet, is there another way to accomplish what the original poster asked if you didn't type `script` _before_? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work in shell/bash script file.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690703/save-current-terminal-scrollback-to-file) by the author, Karl Wilbur, since it does not require the "pre" steps like running script.

The gist:

- triple-click the last line
- hit shift + home
- shift + click first line //(or any place you want!)//

and you have all the needed output selected.

Another way is to use Edit -> Select All in the Terminal menu. But it's only about the whole output selection.